How to create a Windows installer with UAC prompt using electron-forge?
Is it possible for electron-forge to display a UAC prompt before installation? I looked at the Electron Forge documentation, and it doesn't have any configuration to allow a UAC prompt before installation.
I know this is possible with electron-builder using allowElevation:true.
"build": {
    "appId": "your.id",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true
    }
  } 

However, I want to build my Windows desktop app using electron-forge, how can I achieve this?

